# Why is Derivative of a Radon measure measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We have $\mu$, $\nu$ Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. We remember that upper derivative is defined
$$ \overline{D}_{\mu}\nu(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\limsup\limits_{r\to 0} \frac{ \nu(B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r))} & \text{if } \mu(B(x,r))>0  \;(\forall r>0), \\
+\infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$ 
I already know that mapping $x \mapsto B(x,r)$ is upper semicontinous for all $r>0$. But how to prove, that upper derivative is actually measurable? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First, any upper-semicontinuous function is measurable with respect to the Borel sigma algebra.

Second, if $f$ and $g$ are both measurable functions, then the function defined by

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\text{ if } g(x)\neq 0 \\
a \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

is measurable. The easiest way to see this is that the set $\{g(x)=0\}$ is measurable, and if $A$ is a measurable set, a function is measurable if and only if its restrictions to $A$ and $\Omega\setminus A$ are measurable (with respect to the subset measurable space structures).

Finally, the $\limsup$ of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable, and $\limsup_{r\to 0} f(r)=\limsup_{n\to \infty} f(\frac1n)$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but... the problem is that we have here "uncountable sequence". I also made that mistake. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: [link] https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747507/measurability-of-upper-and-lower-derivatives-of-radon-measures[link] there it is.

Comment: @PawełW That's not a problem. I'll edit in the trick - it's a standard technique in measure theory.